# Organizing mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around how to properly organize this database. I have a table of 7,000,000 rows. Each row has a count, date, and a non unique name.

Example:

```
name -- count -- date
blue -- 27 -- 2012-9-05
red  -- 12 -- 2012-10-05
blue -- 19 -- 2012-9-07
blue -- 13 -- 2012-10-4
```

What is the best way to store the sum of each `name` for each month? If a server side language has to be used to do this, I only know PHP.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is the date being stored in an date field type - i suspect not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe, it is better to do in the backend. e.g.

```
SELECT NAME,date,SUM(Count) AS SumCount
FROM <Your TABLE>
GROUP BY NAME,MONTH(date)
```

Comment: Duh, sometimes you just can't wrap your head around a problem. Thanks Niladri!

Comment: You need to include the month in the SELECT columns.